# Get field type in Django's login template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create custom template for Django's build-in login view. At the moment it looks like (`registration/login.html`):

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
        {% include 'registration/form_field.html' %}
    {% endfor %}

    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="{% trans "Log in" %}">
</form>
```

And `registration/form_field.html` file is:

```
<div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
    <input class="form-control" name="{{ field.name }}" placeholder="{{ field.label }}" {% if field.data %}value="{{ field.data }}"{% endif %} />
    {% if field.errors %}
        <span class='text-danger'>{{ field.errors|join:'<br>' }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Everything works as expected, only problem is that password is shown in clear text.

To solve this `type="password"` should be set for `password` field (and `type="text"` for `username` field).

Is it possible to implement this using `field` variable (i.e. something like `{{ field.type }}`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [PasswordInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.PasswordInput) widget in your form definition, that will render as a password field with type="password".

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', 
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

In the templates,

```
{{form.password}}
```

will render this field, which is the cleanest solution.

You may also access the type of the field (as you wanted), like this:

```
{{form.fields.password.widget.input_type}}
```

Note that if you'd like further customization beyond simply rendering the form, there's nothing wrong with just writing your own html for the fields.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I need to modify it a bit to work inside the for loop: `{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}`.